# How can we frame script url in lightning aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Our existing functionality is we are using an header markup on community Page which is given below

[image]
The script is working fine and was loading the cookiepage on load.Now the new requirement has came up for making that script tag as dynamic.

I am following the below approach inorder to show the cookkie popup.but the popup was not loading.can someone suggest where i was going wrong.

### Aura component js controller:

```
doInit  : function(component, event, helper) {
                var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                var script = document.createElement('script');
         
                script.src = "//dummypolicy.dummycookiereports.com/0000e53c167_dummypanel- 
                              dummylanguage.js";  
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.key = "//dummypolicy.dummycookiereports.com/0000e53c167_dummypanel- 
                              dummylanguage.js"; 
                script.helper = this;
                script.id = "script_" + component.getGlobalId();
                var hlp = helper;
                
                head.appendChild(script);

}
```

There was no error and no cookie pop up showing could someone share your thoughts to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this at all, because of the Content Security Policy that's active in Aura. Scripts are only allowed to run in certain ways, and directly injecting a `script` tag isn't one of them. See [Using External JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm) for more information.

Comment: can we do this by using dynamically creating ltng:require? if so can i have possible solution please  @sfdcfox

Comment: any other suggestions inorder to implement this approach?